# How to ignore property during deserialization using JsonSerializerSettings

Tags: c#, .net, json.net

Is there a way to dynamically exclude a property from JSON during the deserialization? An example JSON:

```json
{"time":1516176813,"signature":"IS1cJRqj1FVyTWWDhFpFVw==","data":"ab9984617a6ec835844bacbd47bfb59c"}
```

Here, I'd like to exclude the "si" property and I have extended the DefaultContractResolver:

```cs
public class IgnorePropertiesResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    private readonly HashSet<string> _ignoreProps;

    public IgnorePropertiesResolver(IEnumerable<string> propNamesToIgnore)
    {
        _ignoreProps = new HashSet<string>(propNamesToIgnore);
    }

    protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        JsonProperty property = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);
        if (_ignoreProps.Contains(property.PropertyName))
        {
            property.ShouldSerialize = _ => false;
            property.ShouldDeserialize = _ => false;
        }
        return property;
    }
}
```

However, when I call the DeserializeObject method, the property is still present.

```cs
var ignoredProperties = new List<string> { "si" };
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(source, new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    ContractResolver = new IgnorePropertiesResolver(ignoredProperties)
});
```

I know I can use `JObject.Property(propertyName).Remove()`, but I'd like to avoid that.

Comment: You call `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>`. What is `T`?

Comment: Excluding from deserialization means what after deserialization the property will have default value. It would be easier to deserialize json as usual and then simply set value of known property to default.

Comment: If I put `dynamic` instead of a concrete type, will it have the same effect?

Comment: Experiments with ContractResolver are interesting, but they affect on serialization only.

Comment: @RomanRyzhiy Ah, I see. I guess using `JProperty.Remove()` is the fastest method in that case?

Comment: I prefer a correct target type (struct, class, interface, up to you).

Comment: @RomanRyzhiy I do, too, but the flow here was"retrieve JSON body -> remove si / signature parameter -> hash everything -> compare to the signature parameter.

Comment: @RomanRyzhiy It is not true that ContractResolvers only affect serialization. 
 ContractResolvers are used *both* for serialization and deserialization.  @Authorizer Your contract resolver is working fine.  The problem is that you are trying to exclude `si` but the property in your class is presumably called `signature` to match your JSON.  (There is no property `si` in the JSON that I can see.)  Here is a working fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/VkwnJ2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of a ContractResolver you can use a custom JsonConverter :

```cs
  public class IgnorePropertyConverter<T> : JsonConverter 
        where T : new()
    {
        private readonly HashSet<string> _ignoreProps;

        public IgnorePropertyConverter(IEnumerable<string> propNamesToIgnore)
        {
            _ignoreProps = new HashSet<string>(propNamesToIgnore);
        }
        public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
        {
            return typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
        }

        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            JObject jobject = JObject.Load(reader);

            var model = new T();

            foreach (var prop in _ignoreProps)
                jobject.Remove(prop);

            serializer.Populate(jobject.CreateReader(), model);

            return model;
        }

        public override bool CanWrite
        {
            get { return false; }
        }

        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

```cs
    class MyModel
    {
        public int Time { get; set; }
        public string Data { get; set; }
    }

        var myModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyModel>(json, new IgnorePropertyConverter<MyModel>(new List<string> { "signature" }));
```